# Azure Premium CDN rule redirect subdomain to url

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, azure-cdn

I would like an Azure premium CDN (verizon) rule that will redirect traffic from a subdomain to a url. https://subdomain.example.com -> https://www.example.com/folder. The content specific to the subdomain lives at the `/folder` route.

I've tried this rule:

Feature `URL Redirect` Code `302` Source `^subdomain\.example\.com$` Destination `%{scheme}://www.example.com/folder$1`

The docs mention this use case as Sample scenario #3, but the sample code doesn't redirect the subdomain to the url.

Feature `URL Redirect` Code `302` Source `subdomain(.*)` Destination `%{scheme}://www.example.com/folder$1`

Answer (score 0):

The following rule redirects subdomain traffic to the url correctly:

If Edge CNAME `subdomain.example.com` Feature `URL Redirect` Code `302` Source `($|\/)` Destination `%{scheme}://www.example.com/folder/$1`